# Uniswap Quoter Quotes Not swap?

Tags: solidity, ether, uniswapv3

I'm looking at the uniswap [Quoter Contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol):

```
function quoteExactInputSingle(
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint24 fee,
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96
) public override returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    bool zeroForOne = tokenIn < tokenOut;

    try
        getPool(tokenIn, tokenOut, fee).swap(
            address(this), // address(0) might cause issues with some tokens
            zeroForOne,
            amountIn.toInt256(),
            sqrtPriceLimitX96 == 0
                ? (zeroForOne ? TickMath.MIN_SQRT_RATIO + 1 : TickMath.MAX_SQRT_RATIO - 1)
                : sqrtPriceLimitX96,
            abi.encodePacked(tokenIn, fee, tokenOut)
        )
    {} catch (bytes memory reason) {
        return parseRevertReason(reason);
    }
}
```

I'm confused from the code, on why it would return a quote and not execute the swap.  What prevents to pool from executing the swap?

Comment: It's because `uniswapV3SwapCallback` always reverts

Comment: @0xSanson where is the callback called? I see now it inherits from the callback, but where is it called to actually revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in uniswap V3 the pool contracts call the originating contract during the swap and gives the amount needed to satisfy the swap. This is where the pool must be paid. Instead of sending the token in this Callback, the quoter contract parses that data into a revert message. since the pool swap will fail not receiving tokens, the tx fails, and the quoter sends the data in the revert

quite an ingenious little contract :)